# Firebase / Angular 7 Rewrite Rules

Tags: angular, .htaccess, firebase, angular7, firebase-hosting

I am trying to create one angular application that serves several websites based on template which is retrieve from firestore Firebase. Since I might have more then 100 template, I am dividing each template to modules and when AppModule is launched, it will recognize by url which template to use and which module to load.

The problem is that the only way to load a module is by LazyLoading which will force the url to start with the template name. ex: https://website.com/bluetemplate instead of https://website.com.

Is there a way to load these modules without changing the route or I was thinking if I can hide the first parameter of the url (which is the template name) by firebase rewrites in hosting.

Thank you.